# Show using the definition of the limit: $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^4+x^2+y^2+y^4}{x^2+y^2}=1$

Tags: limits

Definition of limit for this question:

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_1,y_1)} f(x,y)=L $ if
$\forall \epsilon\gt 0, \exists\delta\gt0:$

$0\leq\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}\leq\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon.$

$$\vert\frac{x^4+x^2+y^2+y^4}{x^2+y^2}-1|$$
$$=\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}$$

And we also have $0\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq\delta$.

Any ideas on how to express $\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}$ further to get  $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

Comment: $0\le x^4\le(x^2+y^2)^2$ etc.

Comment: $\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}\leq \frac{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4}{x^2+y^2} = x^2+y^2$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\frac{x^4+ y^4}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{x^4 +2x^2y^2+ y^4}{x^2+y^2} =  x^2 + y^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$x^4 + x^2+y^2+y^4 = (x^4 +y^4 + 2x^2y^2) +x^2 + y^2 - 2x^2y^2 = (x^2 + y^2)^2 - 2x^2y^2 +x^2 + y^2$

Dividing both the sides by $ x^2 + y^2$, we get

$ \frac{x^4 + x^2+y^2+y^4}{x^2 + y^2}= \frac{(x^2 + y^2)^2 - 2x^2y^2 +x^2 + y^2}{x^2 + y^2}= (x^2 + y^2) - \frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^2} + 1 $

Now take the limit, and it’s simple to see that the limit is 1.